# using static_cast to change derived struct member

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-cast

For my new project, I wanted to use my previous code as framework to speed up prototyping by avoiding rewriting code. In the code below, `Derived` struct belongs to the new project and it requires to define a new member, `MoreElaborateMember` which has stuff relevant to the new project. I want to use the function, `foo` from the base project to make changes on `MoreElaborateMember` but I can't. How can I solve this problem without touching to the base code?

```
#include <cassert>

struct SimpleMember
{
    int a;
};

struct MoreElaborateMember: SimpleMember
{
    // lots of other stuff
};

struct Base
{
    SimpleMember member;
};

struct Derived: Base
{
    MoreElaborateMember member;
};

void foo(Base& base)
{
    base.member.a = -1;
}

int main()
{
    Base base;
    Derived derived;
    foo(static_cast<Base&>(derived));
    assert(derived.member.a == -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do without changing `Base` or `Foo`

Comment: If you can't change `foo` there is nothing you can do to make foo use the `MoreElaborateMember` in `Derived`.  You can write an overload for `foo` that takes a `Derived` and does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered composing MoreElaborateMember from SimpleMember instead of inheriting? Might be a bit of boiler plate but I think it would achieve what you want if I've understood correctly.

```
struct SimpleMember
{
    int a;
};

struct MoreElaborateMember
{
    MoreElaborateMember(SimpleMember& s)
        : a(s.a)
    {}
    int& a;
    int b;
};

struct Base
{
    SimpleMember member;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived()
        : Base()
        , member(Base::member)

    {}
    MoreElaborateMember member;
};

void foo(Base& base)
{
    base.member.a = -1;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    Derived derived;

    derived.member.a = 13;
    derived.member.b = 42;
    assert(derived.member.a == 13);
    assert(derived.member.b == 42);

    foo(derived);
    assert(derived.member.a == -1);
    assert(derived.member.b == 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be more comfortable if you use polymorphism.

```
#include <cassert>

struct SimpleMember
{
  int a;
};

struct MoreElaborateMember : SimpleMember
{
  // lots of other stuff
};

struct Base
{
  protected:
  SimpleMember member;

  public:
  virtual void set_member(int m) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
  MoreElaborateMember member;

  virtual void set_member(int m)
  {
    Base::member.a = m;
    member.a = m;
  }
};

void foo(Base* base)
{
  base->set_member(-1);
}

int main()
{
  Derived derived;
  foo(&derived);
  assert(derived.member.a == -1);

  return 0;
}
```